# joining strings in a table according to values in another column

Tags: r, string

I got a table like this:

```
id     words
1     I like school.
2     I hate school.
3     I like cakes.
1     I like cats.
```

Here's what I want to do, joining the strings in each row according to id.

```
id    words
1    I like school. I like cats.
2    I hate school.
3    I like cakes.
```

Is there a package to do that in R?

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` the 'words' together grouped by 'id'.  This can be done with any of the group by operations.  One way it is `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`) and then do the operation was mentioned above.

```
# install.packages(c("data.table"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(words = paste(words, collapse=' ')), by = id]
```

---

A `base R` operation would be to use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(words~id, df1, FUN= paste, collape=' ')
```